# From what latitude can you only travel south?

Tags: latitude-longitude

From what latitude can you only travel south, and from what latitudes can you only travel north?

This question is probably extremely easy and I'm just over thinking it.

Some explanations would be nice as well since I would like to understand this!

Comment: If you are standing on the North or South Poles, in which direction can you travel and in which can you not?

Comment: http://www.ducksters.com/geography/north_pole.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because geography trivia does not pertain to geographic information systems.

Comment: Welcome, @Heather, to GIS SE.

Comment: @vince, et al -- Just because it is a trivial problem for a geographer/geodesist to solve doesn't disqualify it from helping beginners understand the globe and directions. The OP is asking for help in understanding and that is good.

Comment: Heather, i know my colleagues appear to not have treated you well, but was my answer acceptable? Mind Accepting (clicking on check mark beside) it? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

At the north pole, any "straight line" path from that point is automatically going due south, until you change direction.

Likewise, at the south pole, any direct route away is going due north.

All "straight lines" (better known as *great circles* or *geodesics*),  passing through the poles, are known as *meridians* (or lines of constant longitude) and are always exactly N-S in orientation.